# designing a table within a modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

So I have a table within a modal, and I just can't figure out why the css doesn't do anything. What am I missing here?

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead class="okgo">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>MissionType</th>
                                    <th>MissionDate</th>
                                    <th>ElipseNumber</th>
                                    <th>Notes</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.SelectedMission.MissionType</td>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.SelectedMission.MissionDate</td>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.SelectedMission.ElipseNumber</td>
                                    <td>@ViewBag.SelectedMission.Notes</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

css:

```
table.table.table-striped.okgo{
background-color:black;
```

}

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need your css selector to be `table.table.table-striped .okgo` because `.okgo` is nested inside the table, not part of it. Edit for clarity, I put a space between `table.table.table-striped` and `.okgo`

Comment: Thanks bud, unfortunately still nothing

Comment: Ok, so either your css file isn't being loaded properly, or another css rule is overriding this one. [here is a fiddle with it working with code you have and my fix](https://jsfiddle.net/575L4d0y/)

Comment: Yeah it was my browser not updating the css. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in my browser. ctrl+f5 solved it.